# How to apply model trained with PCA and Random Forest to test data?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

In solving one of the machine learning problem, I am implementing PCA on training data and and then applying .transform on train data using sklearn. After observing the variances, I retain only those columns from the transformed data whose variance is large. Then I am training the model using RandomForestClassifier. Now, I am confused how to apply that trained model on the test data as the number of columns of test data and the retained transformed data (on which random forest is applied) is different. Any solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a working example for the problem that you are having if you want specific help with the code. However, note that random forests work in high dimensional spaces, thus PCA before random forests is not probably the best, as PCA does not take into account the target. With random forests it is possible to see the features that are important (see the example for checking the features importance in sklearn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html).

Comment: If I use PCA as first step and then any other algorithm to train a model, how to preprocess test data in order to use that model?

I am using a data set with 335 columns. By applying PCA abd then transform method, I retain 233 columns as the variance value of other columns is too less. Then I am using that data for random forest. The next step is to use it on test data.

Thank you.

Comment: If you train the model just on the training dataset with the reduced dimensions by PCA, you do the same on the test dataset, namely you retain in the test dataset just the columns identified by PCA. In this way, the test dataset matches the dimension of the training dataset.

Comment: How can I know which columns have high variance when applying PCA?

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear, or I am missing something. Aren't you finding already the columns with high variances before training the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it if this is what you seek... ideally u should use the same number of principle components in test as well as train... otherwise defeats the purpose of a hold-out set.

```
pca = PCA(n_components=20)
train_features = pca.fit_transform(train_data)

rfr = sklearn.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, n_jobs = 1, 
                                         random_state = 2016, verbose = 1,
                                         class_weight='balanced',oob_score=True)

rfr.fit(train_features)

test_features = pca.transform(test_data)
rfr.predict(test_features)
```